# EKS: Use cluster config yaml file with eksctl to create a new cluster but node can't join cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am new to eks. I use this cluster config yaml file to create a new cluster,

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
 
metadata:
  name: h2-dev-cluster
  region: us-west-2
 
nodeGroups:
  - name: h2-dev-ng-1
    instanceType: t2.small
    desiredCapacity: 2
    ssh: # use existing EC2 key
      publicKeyName: dev-eks-node
```

but eksctl stuck at

`waiting for at least 1 node(s) to become ready in "h2-dev-ng-1`

then timeout.

I have checked all points from this aws document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html

all the points are right exclude  `The ClusterName in your worker node AWS CloudFormation template`  I can't check because `UserData` has been encrypted by cloudformation.

I access to one of node and type `journalctl -u kubelet`, then find these error

```
Jul 03 08:22:31 ip-192-168-53-151.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[4541]: E0703 08:22:31.007677 4541 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to list *v1beta
Jul 03 08:22:31 ip-192-168-53-151.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[4541]: E0703 08:22:31.391913 4541 kubelet.go:2272] node "ip-192-168-53-151.us-west-2.compute.internal" not found
Jul 03 08:22:31 ip-192-168-53-151.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[4541]: E0703 08:22:31.434158 4541 reflector.go:123] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:459: Failed to list *v1.
Jul 03 08:22:31 ip-192-168-53-151.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[4541]: E0703 08:22:31.492746 4541 kubelet.go:2272] node "ip-192-168-53-151.us-west-2.compute.internal" not found
```

Then I type  `cat /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig` , I see follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
server: MASTER_ENDPOINT
name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
cluster: kubernetes
user: kubelet
name: kubelet
current-context: kubelet
users:
- name: kubelet
user:
exec:
apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
command: /usr/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
args:
- "token"
- "-i"
- "CLUSTER_NAME"
- --region
- "AWS_REGION"
```

I noticed that parameter of server is `MASTER_ENDPINT`. So I run `/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh h2-dev-cluster`  to set cluster name. Find the parameter become right as folllows (I marked url)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
server: https://XXXXXXXX.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
name: kubernetes
```

run `sudo service restart kubectl` but  `journalctl -u kubelet`  still can find the same error, and nodes still can't join cluster

How can I resolve it?

```
eksctl: 0.23.0 rc1 (also test with 0.20.0 has the same error)
kubectl: 1.18.5
os: ubuntu 18.04 (use a new ec2 )
```

Comment: Did you check out your security group?